# cron: output of a script?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I've got a cronjob that looks like this

```
0 0 * * 7 [ $(date +\%d) -le 07 ] && /home/archiver/archiver.sh &> /home/archiver/output
```

And it works from the cron+bash perspective in that it'll run on the first Sunday of every month (or so I assume. It ran today, but we'll see about next Sunday, haha).

But the `&> /home/archiver/output` didn't seem to take. The script is pretty talkative and `/home/archiver/output` has a modified/changed timestamp of 00:00:01, but is completely empty.

What am I missing to capture the script's output?

Comment: Your cron may not be using bash. Can you try `>file 2>&1`. I would use `>>file 2>&1` tho.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 12.04, though I'm not sure what exactly that means for cron. I assume it's /bin/sh based on what the internet says. However, I'm not quite clear on your comment. Should the line end in `>output 2>&1`?

Comment: In your case, `>/home/archiver/output 2>&1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cron seems not to know or use the `&>` shortings from bash. When you write the redirection like this

```
/home/archiver/archiver.sh >/home/archiver/output 2>&1
```

it should work.I would prefer `>>/home/archiver/output 2>&1` to always append to the logfile, too.